# How can I convert two or more dashes to singles and remove all dashes at the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: php, regex

Example: `-this--is---a-test--`

What I want: `this-is-a-test`

Thanks for any answers! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use a combination of [`preg_replace`](http://docs.php.net/preg_replace) and [`trim`](http://docs.php.net/trim):

```
trim(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str), '-')
```

The `preg_replace` call removes multiple dashes and `trim` removes the leading and trailing dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expression....

```
$string = trim($string,'-');

while (stristr($string,'--')) {$c = str_ireplace('--','-',$string);}
```