# How to replace one or more consecutive spaces with one single character?

Tags: php

I want to generate the string like SEO friendly URL. I want that multiple blank space to be eliminated, the single space to be replaced by a hyphen (`-`), then `strtolower` and no special chars should be allowed.

For that I am currently the code like this:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars("This    Is The String");
$string = strtolower(str_replace(htmlspecialchars((' ', '-', $string)));
```

The above code will generate multiple hyphens. I want to eliminate that multiple space and replace it with only one space. In short, I am trying to achieve the SEO friendly URL like string. How do I do it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741553/how-can-i-convert-two-or-more-dashes-to-singles-and-remove-all-dashes-at-the-begi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051889/regular-expression-any-text-to-url-friendly-one, et al.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) to replace any sequence of whitespace chars with a dash...

```
 $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $string);
```

- The outer slashes are delimiters for the pattern - they just mark where the pattern starts and ends
- \s matches any [whitespace character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)
- + causes the previous element to [match 1 or more times](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php). By default, this is 'greedy' so it will eat up as many consecutive matches as it can.
- See the manual page on [PCRE syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for more details

Comment: thank you for the response, i would appreciate if you could explain me what does the first parameter in the function actually does.

Comment: thank you Paul, i got it. i must be studing more about regular expression.

Comment: Great answer Paul. Can I ask, how do you match 2 or more spaces?

Comment: `/\s{2,}/` would match 2 or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('~(\s+)~', '-', $yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "slugify" a string. Try a search on SO or google on "php slugify" or "php slug".

Comment: He's seeking an answer on stackoverflow. Google is not an answer. -1